# 'database is locked' using MobileServiceClient and MobileServiceSQLiteStore in xamarin project

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm relatively new to mobile and async data access and I'm trying to build a line-of-business app from Xamarin starter "cross platform" template in VS2017. It seems that when I do database operations too frequently I get 'database is locked' (most questions deal with roll-your-own sqlite implementations). I had added pretty verbose logging (I have to support non-technical end mobile users).

I changed to (as suggested in other answers) a singleton model for database access which is producing non-traceable (meaning no exceptions are caught and no xamarin log entries) exceptions when calling table.ReadAsync (see below).

As a secondary question, having spent so much time on this and running into so many different roadblocks (no doubt of my own making) I'm wondering whether I'm not following some unspoken rule for mobile development such as "only one async object read per page and design UI for 100% async". Am I trying to do too much? Here is my current "singleton" data access class:

```
public static class MainDataStore
{
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim ReadLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public static bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
    public static MobileServiceClient MobileService { get; set; }
    public static bool UseAuthentication = true;
    public static IMobileServiceSyncTable<User> UserTable;
    public static IMobileServiceSyncTable<Showroom> ShowroomTable;

    public static IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; } //= new ObservableRangeCollection<User>();
    public static IEnumerable<Showroom> Showrooms { get; set; }

    public static void InitializeAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            if (IsInitialized)
                return;

            Logging.D("Starting to initialize main store.");

            AuthenticationHandler handler = null;

            handler = new AuthenticationHandler();

            MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(App.AzureMobileAppUrl, handler)
            {
                SerializerSettings = new MobileServiceJsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    CamelCasePropertyNames = true
                }
            };

            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(Settings.DatabaseName);

            store.DefineTable<User>();
            store.DefineTable<Showroom>();

            MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

            UserTable = MobileService.GetSyncTable<User>();
            ShowroomTable = MobileService.GetSyncTable<Showroom>();

            Logging.D("Finished initializing main store.");

            IsInitialized = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.E(ex); // Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message + ". Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public static async void Load(ECarnavalObjectType type)
    {
        Logging.D("Reading lock entering. Read count: " + ReadLock.CurrentReadCount.ToString());

        // ReadLock.EnterReadLock();

        switch (type)
        {
            case ECarnavalObjectType.Users:
                await GetUsersAsync();
                Users = await UserTable.ToEnumerableAsync();
                break;
            case ECarnavalObjectType.Showrooms:
                await GetShowroomsAsync();
                Showrooms = await ShowroomTable.ToEnumerableAsync();
                break;
        }

        //  ReadLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
    public static async Task GetUsersAsync()
    {
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            try
            {
               // await UserTable.ReadAsync<User>(UserTable.CreateQuery());
await UserTable.PullAsync($"all{typeof(User).Name}", UserTable.CreateQuery());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    public static async Task GetShowroomsAsync()
    {
        await ShowroomTable.ReadAsync<Showroom>(ShowroomTable.CreateQuery());
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the static class to work so far. Compared original vs2017 template and replaced the "ReadAsync" call to "PullAsync". Testing manual buttons that fire off separate pulls for different object types seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same situation, the only difference with your is that my class isn't **static**, If you can, Could you checkt this: https://gist.github.com/phenomx2/e25a1993e02eb8c46f5f901289f633ec and give me some insight ? please @Rodney

Comment: @AdriánRomero It's been a while since I've worked on the project (was cancelled, and my new love is PWAs :). However, I ended up with a pattern of changing the db name on any significant code or model change that resulted in a db lock. Obviously this effectively wiped the local db but I was ok with that as the device was never meant to be the "repository", just "cache". This is part of why I started re-thinking the Xamarin/native model seeing the promise of PWAs. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not awaiting the InitializeAsync(), which means it is likely that the database is still locked and being set up when you go to synchronize it.

Arrange your code in a singleton, then have every single method (read/list/etc.) call `await InitializeAsync()` to initialize the database.  Do an early return on the `InitializeAsync()` method if the database is already created (you've got some good code there for that).

For more info, see my book: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/